# add program to windows 8 URL:mailto program association list

Tags: windows-8.1, mailto, file-association

in windows 8.1
I goto:
Control Panel > All ControlPanel Items > Default Programs > set Associations
and pick
MAILTO (URL:mailto)
it shows the following list to pick from

- Outlook
- Google Chrome
- Mail
- Look for an app in the Store

How do I register my own program (cheapMail.exe) to show up on this list?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to create a windows store app (metro, modern, whatever).
I opned visual studio 2012,
created blank Windows Store (Blank) App,
opened Package.appxmanifest,
clicked on "Declarations"
entered "mailto" for Name:
entered something for Logo: and Desplae name:
then compileded,
 
which registered the app, show it shows up on the list.
I don't think windows 8.1 allows URL:mailto to be associated with a normal old school exe file.
If I am wrong on this please correct me.
I do know you can't just fiddle with the registry.

Comment: When I call my windows store app from a mailto link it shows the splash screen and does nothing else.  It never hits the main app code.

Comment: new problem, when I run this with craigslist it crashes.  craigslist uses a %40 instead of @ as in bob%40ms.com.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21039288/uriformatexception-when-using-40-instead-of-in-mailto-protocol