# UriFormatException when using %40 instead of @ in mailto: protocol

Tags: c#, uri, mailto

I am writing a default mail client to handle when someone clicks mailto:bob@example.com

craigslist mailto links have the form mailto:bob%40example.com
I get an exception when this is used.
here is some simple code to repeat the problem in c#

```
System.Uri u1 = new Uri(@"mailto:bob@ms.com");  // ok so far
System.Uri u2 = new Uri(@"http://somewhere.foo/profile/username%40somewhere.foo"); // still ok
System.Uri u3 = new Uri(@"mailto:bob%40ms.com");  // crash here
```

question 1:
shoudn't mailto:bob%40example.com be a valid uri

question 2:
if it is an invalid uri then how is outlook not crashing on it.

I am using visual studio 2012

Comment: I would not bother with this except that this is seen in craigslist  (qzgwf-4265487696%40sale.craigslist.org?...)

Answer (score 4):

RFC 6068 (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6068.txt), which defines the mailto protocol, does **not** specify that %40 is a valid syntax to replace @ as a username/domain separator.

It does specify that if a *username* contains a @, such as in the case `hello@you@domain.com`, you can use %40 to escape it to `hello%40you@domain.com`. But nowhere does it state that `hello%40domain.com` would be a valid mailto URI.

And if Microsoft decided to support it in Outlook, that still doesn't change the fact that the RFC, which is authoritative, doesn't define it -- so I'd say, Microsoft probably put it in for reasons of robustness, or maybe it's a side-effect of them parsing any URI for %xx syntax...

Comment: my problem is that I am writing a quick and dirty email client in windows app store and craigslist mailto links use %40 instead of @ sign.    I put code on http://pastebin.com/HuPA96N3.  the crash is on line 85. Are you aware of any workaround?

Comment: Are you sure that, after the line `var _args = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;`, your variable `_args` is not `null`?

Comment: I just checked, is not null, it even has valid values for _args.SplashScreen and  _args.PreviousExecutionState, I think there is a bug in the System.Uri class, I put some simple code up at http://pastebin.com/9WX1skzt I think that mailto:bob%40ms.com is a valid uri because that is what craigslist is using and because outlook works with it, so at least microsoft is aware of a work around

Comment: Optionally I would like to get access to the raw arguments passed to a windows app program that was activate with mailto protocol.  I can then change the %40 to @ myself and create a new System.Uri instance.